# Is a complex matrix that skew-Hermitian and nilpotent (with index 2) the null matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can it be proven that if an $N \times N$ matrix $A$ with complex entries is both skew-Hermitian ($A^\dagger = - A$) and nilpotent with degree two ($A^2 = 0$), then $A=0$? The Hermitian conjugate is $A^\dagger = A^H = (A^*)^T = (A^T)^*$.

If this is not true in general, could it true (1) when $N$ is even, and/or (2) in the specific case where $A=[B,C]=BC-CB$ where $B=B^\dagger = B^{-1}$ and $C=C^{\dagger}=C^{-1}$ are Hermitian and unitary (involutory)?

I could not find an answer to this particular case in my search of this site. Note that I specifically have $A^2=0$ for any $N$.

Comment: I think that is true - doesn't it follow from diagonalizability of skew-Hermitian matrices?

Comment: Oh, I somehow didn't realize skew-Hermitian matrices were also diagonalizable lol. Thanks! OK so A's eigenvalues are all imaginary. But I guess if A is nilpotent, its complex eigenvalues must be zero? So all eigenvalues are 0, and A=0.

Comment: That's right! But I think there's perhaps an even simpler argument - since $0 = A^2 = A^\dagger A$, looking at the $(i, i)$ entry tells you that $\overline{A_i}^{\mathsf T} A_i = \lVert A_i \rVert^2 = 0$, so each column of $A$ is the zero vector! You're welcome to post an answer to your question in your own words with either or both of these arguments and then accept it so that your question is closed. (I will give you an upvote :) )

Comment: More generally, any [normal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix) is diagonalizable, and if it is nilpotent it is $0$.